# Oracle convert Timestamp to Date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have date like :

```
2020/05/09T02:40:03
2020/05/16T02:40:03
2020/05/15T02:40:03
```

I need to convert it into Date format 'dd/mm/yyyy'.

My query

```
select cast(date_registered as date) as Reg_date from employee
```

Error:

```
Literal does not match format string

Note:I have also used TO_Char , TO_Date but not working
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, a date data type is always stores as 7-bytes consisting of century, year-of-century, month, day, hours, minutes and seconds; so, asking to convert something that has year-to-seconds components to a date does not require you to do anything:

```sql
SELECT date_registered AS reg_date FROM employee
```

Now, if you are storing `date_registered` as a string data type rather than as a date data type then you need to convert using `TO_DATE`:

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE( date_registered, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS' ) AS reg_date
FROM   employee
```

However, you should not do this and you should fix the underlying problem that you are storing dates as strings and not dates. You can solve this by converting the data type of the column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE employee ADD ( date_registered2 DATE );
UPDATE employee
  SET date_registered2 = TO_DATE( date_registered, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS' );
ALTER TABLE employee DROP COLUMN date_registered;
ALTER TABLE employee RENAME COLUMN date_registered2 TO date_registered;
```

*(Note: The queries below assume that you have "fixed" the table so that the `date_registered` column has the date data type; if you do not want to do this then you will need to include the `TO_DATE` conversion as well.)*

If you want the output to be a date where the time component is truncated back to midnight then:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC( date_registered ) AS reg_date
FROM   employee
```

*(Note: The displayed date will still have hours, minutes and seconds components but they will all be zero after being passed through `TRUNC`.)*

If you want it in a specific format, without the time component, then you need to output it as a formatted string (since the date data type does not have an associated format) using `TO_CHAR`:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR( date_registered, 'DD/MM/YYYY' ) AS reg_date
FROM   employee
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ad2d46741aa16dad45cbecf11b86329c)*

Answer (score 2):

First, what you tried to convert to `date` is not a `timestamp`, it is a string.

Second, `cast(... to date)` does not take a format model - it simply relies on your session `nls_date_format` parameter, which doesn't match the string's date format. (Especially the boilerplate, hard-coded T in the middle, which has no meaning in Oracle.)

You need `to_date()` with an appropriate format model. Notice the handling of hardcoded string fragments (they appear in double-quotes in the format model).

```
select to_date(date_registered, 'yyyy/mm/dd"T"hh24:mi:ss') as reg_date 
from   employee;
```

Comment: Thanks @mathguy ,  It is working. But now if i want to filter between 2 dates on same date_registered column, im using query : 

select * from employee where
date_registered between to_date('2020/05/09T02:40:03', 'yyyy/mm/dd"T"hh24:mi:ss')
AND to_date('2020/12/17T07:38:09', 'yyyy/mm/dd"T"hh24:mi:ss');
  --it is giving me error : Literal does not match format string, Any suggestions

Comment: @tom Do not store dates as string data types; store them as the date data type and then your query will work. If you are going to store them as (almost) ISO8601 formatted strings then just do `select * from employee where date_registered between '2020/05/09T02:40:03' AND '2020/12/17T07:38:09'`